# Changing locale for translating app

Tags: java, android

I have an app where I have translated the @strings for es_ES and en_US. The thing is I don't want them to change taking into account the location. I mean: if the locale of the phone is  "es-AR" or "cat_ES", I want it to be in Spanish and, in the cases wher the locale isn't "es_XX" or "xx_ES", I want it to be in english. For noticing these situations, I have this boolean:

```
 countryES =("ES".equals(Locale.getDefault().getCountry())|| "es".equals(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));
```

This variable will be true if the app must be displayed in spanish and false if it should be english. As I have done the translation using the "Locale in Editor" of android studio, I'd like to know how to change the local like this:

```
if(countryES)
{
    //Change local to es_ES
} 
else
{
     //Change local to en_US
}
```

Comment: Just use `es` and `en`, without `-rXY` for your folder names. And remove all other values folders. One of the two (the default one) can be set **without** any suffix.

Comment: I'm sorry but, could you explain it in another way? I didn't understand your suggestion.

Comment: Your `strings.xml` files are located in your `values-xy-rZK`. Just remove the `-rZK` part from the folder names.

Comment: Yes but that would make it to use one string pack or the other if the location is one or another, but that is not what I want. The thing is I want to change the location configuration for the system to use some strings or other taking my variable into consideration,

Comment: This is what I do (5 languages, currently). You choose the language in the preferences and the activity is restarted after updating the locale. It works immediately. And the next time you start your app, it reads the preference and sets the locale accordingly.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you add some code to see it more clearly?

Comment: Well, it's simply too broad. It involves loading and saving from/to the  SharedPReferences, setting the locale dynamically and persisting the instance state of some variables. Not even to mention that I use a custom ListPreference to show the default languages with their (simplified) flags (i.e.: for Spain and Germany I removed the central symbol, leaving only the color bands).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, what worked for me was the following (although there might be other options):

```
if(countryES)
{
    //Change local to es_ES
   Locale localeEs = new Locale("es");
                Locale.setDefault(localeEs);
                Configuration configEs = new Configuration();
                configEs.locale = localeEs;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configEs, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
} 
else
{
     //Change local to en_US
   Locale localeEs = new Locale("en");
                Locale.setDefault(localeEs);
                Configuration configEs = new Configuration();
                configEs.locale = localeEs;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configEs, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```